# express Unexpected token k

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I have an express application which is designed to be a simple restful api.
this is my app.js file adding the body parser middleware

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

**using bodyparser 1.15.2**

this is my basic routing file

```
... 
r.post('/search/:keyword', function(req, res){
var __keyword = req.params.keyword,
console.log(req.body);
```

I'm using postman for sending requests, when I'm using the raw tab for sending the request with the *application/json* header the result is fine. The code this way of sending requests generates looks like this

```
POST /api/search/mykeyword HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
{
    "key": "value"
}
```

when using the x-form-urlencoded option in postman I'm getting this error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token k
    at parse (D:<projectpath>\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:83:15)
    at D:<projectpath>\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:116:18
    at invokeCallback (D:<projectpath>\node_modules\body-parser\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:262:16)
    at done (D:<projectpath>\node_modules\body-parser\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:251:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (D:<projectpath>\node_modules\body-parser\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:307:7)
    at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:913:12)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:442:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:356:17)
```

the request then looks like this

```
POST /api/search/mykeyword HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

{
    "key": "value"
}
```

For me this looks exactly the same, but it's producing this error? Is this a bug in bodyparser, express or postman? Or is this my mistake?
When only calling

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

the req.body object is always empty, no matter which of the described ways I use

Comment: I think you are setting the body type as `x-www-form-urlencoded` and Content-type as `application/json`. Can you change Content-Type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in headers and check?

Answer (score 0):

when you use raw Body, select `JSON (application/json)` instead of `Text` and the `req.body` will be populated

you can also remove `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));`

if you want use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, check if Postman hasn't `application/json` inside Headers tab

otherwise bodyParser throws this Error

https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/commit/06a5182e6b1e51eb6723531b36d4ec173ec41268#diff-2f6af76c010570bda08534da011fac9fR83